# How do I send email using logic app by passing user id , subject , attachment from databricks

Tags: smtp, databricks, azure-logic-apps, mailing-list

Need to send email to a list of user from databricks , since we do not have a SMTP server setup we need to use the Logic app to do the task. Is there a way to call the logic app to send the mail we can pass the userid , subject and attachments from databricks(azure blobs)

Since this is a new territory for me and i can not see any ongoing threads or material so posting this question

Comment: If you can make a HTTP call from Bricks then you can call a HTTP endpoint in LogicApps that does the work.

Answer (score 0):

One way to make this work is that you can use a regular Rest Api POST call to send the data from databricks to logic apps. And from there you can send the emails using the related connector.

```
import requests

url = "<Your_Logic_App_URL>"
myResponse = requests.post(url,data={"emailId":"<Your_User_Id>" , "subject":"<Your_Subject>" , "attachment":"<Your_Attachments>"})
```

To automate this, I have used `When a HTTP request is received` with a sample payload to generate schema which generates outputs parameters which can be used to send emails in my logic apps. Below is the flow in my logic apps.

[image]